# Android Studio Sqlite database login error

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am making an application to expend my knowledge and I am having this problem where I have a username to login with when i click on `login` button to login to application it gives error. I have tried couple of things but none worked so far. Here is the error code I believe there is something wrong with the database query or `onclick` method any help will be appreciated thank you.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.bulkbuys.bulkbuysapp, PID: 23940
      android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.bulkbuys.bulkbuysapp.Menu launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }
          at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1844)
          at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1531)
          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4403)
          at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4362)
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
          at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4686)
          at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4654)
          at com.bulkbuys.bulkbuysapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
          at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11180)
          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748)
          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.bulkbuys.bulkbuysapp;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editTextUsername;
    Button buttonLogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Username);
        buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_Login);
        //create preferences - used to store currently logged in user
    }

    public void login(View view) {
        String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString(); //get Username from editText box
        DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(this, null, null, 7);
        Admin a = dbHandler.findAdmin(username);
        Log.i("Login: ","Trying to login with " + username);

        if (username.equals("rick"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            if (a == null) //if T is null no match came back, therefore incorrect username or password.
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Login failed - Username Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public void clear(View view) {
        editTextUsername.setText("");
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="828dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:divider="#262626">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_Username"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:hint="Username" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="400dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button_Login"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                android:onClick="login"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                android:onClick="clear"
                android:text="clear"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

DBHandler

```
package com.bulkbuys.bulkbuysapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

import java.util.ArrayList; 

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 19;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "GradeDB.db";
    //Declare Tables in Database
    private static final String TABLE_CUSTOMERS = "customers";
    private static final String Admin = "admin";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_COMPANYNAME = "Company Name";
    public static final String COLUMN_ADRESS = "Adress";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "Email";
    public static final String COLUMN_ABN = "Abn";
    public static final String COLUMN_MOBILENO = "Mobile Number";
    public static final String COLUMN_COMPANYNO = "Company Number";

    public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "User Name";


    public DBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_ADMIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Admin + "(" +
                COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT)  ";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ADMIN_TABLE);


        String CREATE_CUSTOMERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CUSTOMERS + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COLUMN_COMPANYNAME + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_ADRESS + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_ABN + " TEXT. " +
                COLUMN_MOBILENO + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_COMPANYNO + " TEXT) ";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CUSTOMERS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBHandler.Admin);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBHandler.TABLE_CUSTOMERS);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    //search for product
    public Admin findAdmin(String username) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Admin + " WHERE username = '" +
                username + "'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //run query with cursor
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        Admin a = new Admin();

        //move to first existing object
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do { //****** This IF loop may be pointless need to mess with...
                if (username.equals(cursor.getString(3))) { //If a username matches one in the DB add info into Teacher object
                    a.setUsername(cursor.getString(0));
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
        }
        else //no match found return a null object
        {
            a = null;
            db.close();
        }

        return a;
    }

    public void addCustomers(Customers customers) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); // simpler way of inserting into DB
        //ID isn't added as the ID will automatically be assigned
        values.put(COLUMN_ID, customers.getId());
        values.put(COLUMN_COMPANYNAME, customers.getCompanyname());
        values.put(COLUMN_ADRESS, customers.getAdress());
        values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, customers.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_ABN, customers.getAbn());
        values.put(COLUMN_MOBILENO, customers.getMobileno());
        values.put(COLUMN_COMPANYNO, customers.getCompanyno());

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.insert(TABLE_CUSTOMERS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<Customers> listCustomers() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CUSTOMERS + " ORDER BY " + COLUMN_ID;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ArrayList<Customers> list = new ArrayList<>(); //Array to store customer
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do { //run loop through all results and store each customer into arraylist
                Customers p = new Customers();
                p.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                p.setCompanyname(cursor.getString(1));
                p.setAdress(cursor.getString(2));
                p.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
                p.setAbn(cursor.getString(4));
                p.setMobileno(cursor.getString(5));
                p.setCompanyno(cursor.getString(6));
                list.add(p);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return list;
    }

    public boolean deleteCustomert(int id) {
        boolean success = false;
        //create query
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CUSTOMERS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + " = '" + id + "'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //run query
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        Customers Customers = new Customers(); //temp
        //move to first object
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) //if exists delete object
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            Customers.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            db.delete(TABLE_CUSTOMERS, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(Customers.getId())});
            success = true;
            cursor.close();
        }
        db.close();
        return success;
    }

    public Customers findCustomers(String id) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CUSTOMERS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + " = '" +
                id + "'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //run query with cursor
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        Customers p = new Customers();

        return p;
    }
}
```

Android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bulkbuys.bulkbuysapp">

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".CustomerListPage"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Menu"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have got this extra class, i have tried something with it but it didn't work

```
package com.bulkbuys.bulkbuysapp;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Admin implements Serializable {

    private String username;

    public Admin() {
    }

    public Admin(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " / Username: " + username;
    }
}
```

Menu.class

```
package com.bulkbuys.bulkbuysapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Menu extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

    Button buttonclick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_customer);

    buttonclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // use Intent

            Intent intent1= new Intent(Menu.this,CustomerListPage.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: As your exception says Menu Activity not present in your project

Comment: Show your Menu activity

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have putted menu.class in the question.

Comment: @Onur Clean-Rebuild and uninstall old app and run

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`ActivityNotFoundException`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ActivityNotFoundException.html)

> This exception is thrown when a call to startActivity(Intent) or one
>   of its variants fails because an Activity can not be found to execute
>   the given Intent.

**FYI**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Make sure, **Menu** `Activity` is present or not.

Rectify Statement. Use **`,`** instead of **`.`**

**Don't**

```
String CREATE_CUSTOMERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CUSTOMERS + "(" +
        COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        COLUMN_COMPANYNAME + " TEXT , " +
        COLUMN_ADRESS + " TEXT , " +
        COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT , " +
        COLUMN_ABN + " TEXT. " +
        COLUMN_MOBILENO + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_COMPANYNO + " TEXT) ";
```

**Do**

```
    String CREATE_CUSTOMERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CUSTOMERS + "(" +
        COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " +
        COLUMN_COMPANYNAME + " TEXT , " +
        COLUMN_ADRESS + " TEXT , " +
        COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT , " +
        COLUMN_ABN + " TEXT , " +
        COLUMN_MOBILENO + " TEXT , " +
        COLUMN_COMPANYNO + " TEXT) ";
```

**EDIT**

> MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)

```
public void clear(View view) {
      //  editTextUsername.setText(""); comment setText method
    }
```

Comment: That's ok but is not what is causing the exception. In fact, is crashing in the startActivity invocation. My guess is that Menu activity is not defined.

Comment: @Pablo Thank you for your answer, I have changed the dot mistake, but i don't get the part where it doesn't find Menu.class. I am clearly saying in the code when the button is clicked go to Menu.class. Or am i missing something ?

Comment: @Onur Kindly DEBUG your app, please. Add breakpoint beside `public void login(View view)`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have done what you said, no luck so far but i have done something i took out the part after public void login(View view) in MainActivity and changed to this.                                                                                                public void login(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }                          and it worked this way but this way just clicking on login is enough to get to the next screen but i would like to have a username entry :/

Comment: @Onur for test case comment `editTextUsername.setText("");` line

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya To be honest i didn't understand what you suggested. Can you explained it what i am supposed to do with editTextUsername.setText("");

Comment: your error logcat saying `MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)`. Problem coming from line no 52.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Can it be database problem what i am thinking is i did not defined rick in database as a username in java class it says if username equals rick then login.

Comment: @Onur I assume sloppy mistake costing you.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya  It probably is i just can't find what it is ughh. I got a question do you have to define username and password like default one to login to app in sqlite database or saying if username equals to "name" is enough for it to work ?

Comment: @Onur Solved this yet?